# transparent background for responsive-tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this JS library http://openam.github.io/bootstrap-responsive-tabs/. 
I can't manage to set their background transparent (or any other color).

It seems the problem is that tab styles are updated by the js library when the accordion tabs are created, always with white background-color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following CSS rule:

```
.nav-tabs > li.active > a,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus,
.nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned how you're trying to change the background color.

However, this one might help as per my assumption, add this to your css:

```
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover{
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.nav-tabs > li > a` is the selector for links in the tabs
`.nav-tabs > li` is the selector for the tabs themselves. You can use those two to change the appearance of the tabs, also note the class `.active` is added to some of them and the background is not consistently set on the `li` or the `a` element - sometimes its the first other times the other.